# Syntax quoting in Scheme macros

Tags: macros, scheme, primes

I am trying to write a Scheme macro that loops over the prime numbers. Here is a simple version of the macro:

```
(define-syntax do-primes
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((do-primes (p lo hi) (binding ...) (test res ...) exp ...)
      (do ((p (next-prime (- lo 1)) (next-prime p)) binding ...)
          ((or test (< hi p)) res ...) exp ...))
    ((do-primes (p lo) (binding ...) (test res ...) exp ...)
      (do ((p (next-prime (- lo 1)) (next-prime p)) binding ...)
          (test res ...) exp ...))
    ((do-primes (p) (binding ...) (test res ...) exp ...)
      (do ((p 2 (next-prime p)) binding ...) (test res ...) exp ...))))
```

The `do-primes` macro expands to a `do` with three possible syntaxes: if the first argument to `do-primes` is `(p lo hi)` then the `do` loops over the primes from `lo` to `hi` unless iteration is stopped early by the termination clause, if the first argument to `do-primes` is `(p lo)` then the `do` loops over the primes starting from `lo` and continuing until the termination clause stops the iteration, and if the first argument to `do-primes` is `(p)` then the `do` loops over the primes starting from 2 and continuing until the termination clause stops the iteration. Here are some sample uses of the `do-primes` macro:

```
; these lines display the primes less than 25
(do-primes (p 2 25) () (#f) (display p) (newline))
(do-primes (p 2) () ((< 25 p)) (display p) (newline))
(do-primes (p) () ((< 25 p)) (display p) (newline))

; these lines return a list of the primes less than 25
(do-primes (p 2 25) ((ps (list) (cons p ps))) (#f (reverse ps)))
(do-primes (p 2) ((ps (list) (cons p ps))) ((< 25 p) (reverse ps)))
(do-primes (p) ((ps (list) (cons p ps))) ((< 25 p) (reverse ps)))

; these lines return the sum of the primes less than 25
(do-primes (p 2 25) ((s 0 (+ s p))) (#f s))
(do-primes (p 2) ((s 0 (+ s p))) ((< 25 p) s))
(do-primes (p) ((s 0 (+ s p))) ((< 25 p) s))
```

What I want to do is write a version of the `do-primes` macro that uses a local version of the `next-prime` function; I want to do that because I can make the `next-prime` function run faster than my general-purpose `next-prime` function because I know the environment in which it will be called. I tried to write the macro like this:

```
(define-syntax do-primes
  (let ()
    (define (prime? n)
      (if (< n 2) #f
        (let loop ((f 2))
          (if (< n (* f f)) #t
            (if (zero? (modulo n f)) #f
              (loop (+ f 1)))))))
    (define (next-prime n)
      (let loop ((n (+ n 1)))
        (if (prime? n) n (loop (+ n 1)))))
  (lambda (x) (syntax-case x ()
    ((do-primes (p lo hi) (binding ...) (test res ...) exp ...)
      (syntax
        (do ((p (next-prime (- lo 1)) (next-prime p)) binding ...)
            ((or test (< hi p)) res ...) exp ...)))
    ((do-primes (p lo) (binding ...) (test res ...) exp ...)
      (syntax
        (do ((p (next-prime (- lo 1)) (next-prime p)) binding ...)
            (test res ...) exp ...)))
    ((do-primes (p) (binding ...) (test res ...) exp ...)
      (syntax
        (do ((p 2 (next-prime p)) binding ...) (test res ...) exp ...))))))))
```

(Ignore the `prime?` and `next-prime` functions, which are there only for illustration. The real version of the `do-primes` macro will use a segmented sieve for small primes and switch to a Baillie-Wagstaff pseudoprime test for larger primes.) But that doesn't work; I get an error message telling me that that I am trying "to reference out-of-phase identifier next-prime." I understand the problem. But my macrology wizardry is insufficient to solve it.

Can someone show me how to write the `do-primes` macro?

**EDIT:** Here is the final macro:

```
(define-syntax do-primes (syntax-rules () ; syntax for iterating over primes

  ; (do-primes (p lo hi) ((var init next) ...) (pred? result ...) expr ...)

  ; Macro do-primes provides syntax for iterating over primes. It expands to
  ; a do-loop with variable p bound in the same scope as the rest of the (var
  ; init next) variables, as if it were defined as (do ((p (primes lo hi) (cdr
  ; p)) (var init next) ...) (pred result ...) expr ...). Variables lo and hi
  ; are inclusive; for instance, given (p 2 11), p will take on the values 2,
  ; 3, 5, 7 and 11. If hi is omitted the iteration continues until stopped by
  ; pred?. If lo is also omitted iteration starts from 2. Some examples:

  ;   three ways to display the primes less than 25
  ;   (do-primes (p 2 25) () (#f) (display p) (newline))
  ;   (do-primes (p 2) () ((< 25 p)) (display p) (newline))
  ;   (do-primes (p) () ((< 25 p)) (display p) (newline))

  ;   three ways to return a list of the primes less than 25
  ;   (do-primes (p 2 25) ((ps (list) (cons p ps))) (#f (reverse ps)))
  ;   (do-primes (p 2) ((ps (list) (cons p ps))) ((< 25 p) (reverse ps)))
  ;   (do-primes (p) ((ps (list) (cons p ps))) ((< 25 p) (reverse ps)))

  ;   three ways to return the sum of the primes less than 25
  ;   (do-primes (p 2 25) ((s 0 (+ s p))) (#f s))
  ;   (do-primes (p 2) ((s 0 (+ s p))) ((< 25 p) s))
  ;   (do-primes (p) ((s 0 (+ s p))) ((< 25 p) s))

  ;   functions to count primes and return the nth prime (from P[1] = 2)
  ;   (define (prime-pi n) (do-primes (p) ((k 0 (+ k 1))) ((< n p) k)))
  ;   (define (nth-prime n) (do-primes (p) ((n n (- n 1))) ((= n 1) p)))

  ; The algorithm used to generate primes is a segmented Sieve of Eratosthenes
  ; up to 2^32. For larger primes, a segmented sieve runs over the sieving
  ; primes up to 2^16 to produce prime candidates, then a Baillie-Wagstaff
  ; pseudoprimality test is performed to confirm the number is prime.

  ; If functions primes, expm, jacobi, strong-pseudoprime?, lucas, selfridge
  ; and lucas-pseudoprime? exist in the outer environment, they can be removed
  ; from the macro.

  ((do-primes (p lo hi) (binding ...) (test result ...) expr ...)
    (do-primes (p lo) (binding ...) ((or test (< hi p)) result ...) expr ...))

  ((do-primes (pp low) (binding ...) (test result ...) expr ...)

    (let* ((limit (expt 2 16)) (delta 50000) (limit2 (* limit limit))
           (sieve (make-vector delta #t)) (ps #f) (qs #f) (bottom 0) (pos 0))

      (define (primes n) ; sieve of eratosthenes
        (let ((sieve (make-vector n #t)))
          (let loop ((p 2) (ps (list)))
            (cond ((= n p) (reverse ps))
                  ((vector-ref sieve p)
                    (do ((i (* p p) (+ i p))) ((<= n i))
                      (vector-set! sieve i #f))
                    (loop (+ p 1) (cons p ps)))
                  (else (loop (+ p 1) ps))))))

      (define (expm b e m) ; modular exponentiation
        (let loop ((b b) (e e) (x 1))
          (if (zero? e) x
            (loop (modulo (* b b) m) (quotient e 2)
                  (if (odd? e) (modulo (* b x) m) x)))))

      (define (jacobi a m) ; jacobi symbol
        (let loop1 ((a (modulo a m)) (m m) (t 1))
          (if (zero? a) (if (= m 1) t 0)
            (let ((z (if (member (modulo m 8) (list 3 5)) -1 1)))
              (let loop2 ((a a) (t t))
                (if (even? a) (loop2 (/ a 2) (* t z))
                  (loop1 (modulo m a) a
                         (if (and (= (modulo a 4) 3)
                                  (= (modulo m 4) 3))
                             (- t) t))))))))

      (define (strong-pseudoprime? n a) ; strong pseudoprime base a
        (let loop ((r 0) (s (- n 1)))
          (if (even? s) (loop (+ r 1) (/ s 2))
            (if (= (expm a s n) 1) #t
              (let loop ((r r) (s s))
                (cond ((zero? r) #f)
                      ((= (expm a s n) (- n 1)) #t)
                      (else (loop (- r 1) (* s 2)))))))))

      (define (lucas p q m n) ; lucas sequences u[n] and v[n] and q^n (mod m)
        (define (even e o) (if (even? n) e o))
        (define (mod n) (if (zero? m) n (modulo n m)))
        (let ((d (- (* p p) (* 4 q))))
          (let loop ((un 1) (vn p) (qn q) (n (quotient n 2))
                     (u (even 0 1)) (v (even 2 p)) (k (even 1 q)))
            (if (zero? n) (values u v k)
              (let ((u2 (mod (* un vn))) (v2 (mod (- (* vn vn) (* 2 qn))))
                    (q2 (mod (* qn qn))) (n2 (quotient n 2)))
                (if (even? n) (loop u2 v2 q2 n2 u v k)
                  (let* ((uu (+ (* u v2) (* u2 v)))
                         (vv (+ (* v v2) (* d u u2)))
                         (uu (if (and (positive? m) (odd? uu)) (+ uu m) uu))
                         (vv (if (and (positive? m) (odd? vv)) (+ vv m) vv))
                         (uu (mod (/ uu 2))) (vv (mod (/ vv 2))))
                    (loop u2 v2 q2 n2 uu vv (* k q2)))))))))

      (define (selfridge n) ; initialize lucas sequence
        (let loop ((d-abs 5) (sign 1))
          (let ((d (* d-abs sign)))
            (cond ((< 1 (gcd d n)) (values d 0 0))
                  ((= (jacobi d n) -1) (values d 1 (/ (- 1 d) 4)))
                  (else (loop (+ d-abs 2) (- sign)))))))

      (define (lucas-pseudoprime? n) ; standard lucas pseudoprime
        (call-with-values
          (lambda () (selfridge n))
          (lambda (d p q)
            (if (zero? p) (= n d)
              (call-with-values
                (lambda () (lucas p q n (+ n 1)))
                (lambda (u v qkd) (zero? u)))))))

      (define (init lo) ; initialize sieve, return first prime
        (set! bottom (if (< lo 3) 2 (if (odd? lo) (- lo 1) lo)))
        (set! ps (cdr (primes limit))) (set! pos 0)
        (set! qs (map (lambda (p) (modulo (/ (+ bottom p 1) -2) p)) ps))
        (do ((p ps (cdr p)) (q qs (cdr q))) ((null? p))
          (do ((i (+ (car p) (car q)) (+ i (car p)))) ((<= delta i))
            (vector-set! sieve i #f)))
        (if (< lo 3) 2 (next)))

      (define (advance) ; advance to next segment
        (set! bottom (+ bottom delta delta)) (set! pos 0)
        (do ((i 0 (+ i 1))) ((= i delta)) (vector-set! sieve i #t))
        (set! qs (map (lambda (p q) (modulo (- q delta) p)) ps qs))
        (do ((p ps (cdr p)) (q qs (cdr q))) ((null? p))
          (do ((i (car q) (+ i (car p)))) ((<= delta i))
            (vector-set! sieve i #f))))

      (define (next) ; next prime after current prime
        (when (= pos delta) (advance))
        (let ((p (+ bottom pos pos 1)))
          (if (and (vector-ref sieve pos) (or (< p limit2)
                (and (strong-pseudoprime? p 2) (lucas-pseudoprime? p))))
              (begin (set! pos (+ pos 1)) p)
              (begin (set! pos (+ pos 1)) (next)))))

      (do ((pp (init low) (next)) binding ...) (test result ...) expr ...)))

  ((do-primes (p) (binding ...) (test result ...) expr ...)
    (do-primes (p 2) (binding ...) (test result ...) expr ...))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get correct phasing, your `next-prime` needs to defined within the macro output. Here's one way to go about it (tested with Racket):

```
(define-syntax do-primes
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((do-primes (p lo hi) (binding ...) (test res ...) exp ...)
     (do-primes (p lo) (binding ...) ((or test (< hi p)) res ...) exp ...))
    ((do-primes (p lo) (binding ...) (test res ...) exp ...)
     (let ()
       (define (prime? n)
         ...)
       (define (next-prime n)
         ...)
       (do ((p (next-prime (- lo 1)) (next-prime p)) binding ...)
           (test res ...)
         exp ...)))
    ((do-primes (p) (binding ...) (test res ...) exp ...)
     (do-primes (p 2) (binding ...) (test res ...) exp ...))))
```

This way, this defines the `prime?` and `next-prime` in the most local scope possible, while not having tons of duplicate code in your macro definition (since the 1- and 3-argument forms are simply rewritten to use the 2-argument form).

Comment: Thank you. Here is another use of `do-primes`, returning the _n_ th prime, counting from P[1] = 2: `(define (nth-prime n) (do-primes (p) ((n n (- n 1))) ((= n 1) p)))`.

Comment: I added the final macro to the original question, in case you would like to look at it. The macro has been lightly tested.